# jQuery :not() with parameter as value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a simple radio button function, that enables an input text on click; if other radio elems are clicked, then the input back to disabled state.

Everything works fine, until I wanted to add the ID elem as a parameter.
Right now I'm using a CSS selector :not to exclude any others radio elems.

```
'input[type=radio]:not(element)'
```

Is there any jQuery approach to replace this not working line?

```
function enableInputonClick(element) {
    var input = $('.form-control-optional');

    $(element).on('ifClicked', function() {
        if(input.length && input.attr("disabled", "disabled")) {
            input.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });

    $('input[type=radio]:not(element)').on('ifClicked', function() {
        if(input.length && input.attr("disabled", "")) {
            input.attr("disabled");
        }
    });
}
enableInputonClick("#myRadioEl");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your element is a selector string, you can just use string concatenators `+`:

```
$('input[type=radio]:not(' + element + ')') ...
```

Or you replace the CSS `:not()` with the jQuery `.not()` (as mentioned in the comments):

```
$('input[type=radio]').not(element).on( ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I have found my error. I was using the not() inside '' . SOLUTION: `$('input[type=radio]').not(element).on( ...`

Comment: Yes, that's also possible. Glad I could help! Appreciate an upvote/accept ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input[type=radio]:not(' + element + ')')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can rewrite it the following way.

```
$('input[type=radio]').not(element).on('ifClicked', function() {
```